# VueJS - How to use the response of one API call in another API call in the same component

Tags: api, vue.js, response

Here is my scenario, i am trying to use the id coming from one API response in another API :

Below is Component.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="Contents">
      <div class="vx-col" v-for="idea in ideas" v-bind:key="idea.id">
          <vx-card>
            ...
            <div>
              {{idea.name}} of {{idea.id}}
            </div>
            <div v-if="sum">
              {{sum.total}}
            </div>
            ...
          </vx-card>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
...

async created () {

  await this.$http.get('/ideas')
    .then((response) => { this.ideas = response.data })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
},
methods: {

  getSumOfIdeas(id){
    this.$http.get('/sum_of_ideas/'+ id +'/everything')
      .then((response) => { this.sum = response.data })
      .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
  }
},
mounted (){
  this.getSumOfIdeas(this.ideas.id)   //Here i am trying to give that id coming from the /ideas 
}
</script>
```

Here is what console.log(response.data) gives in /ideas:

[image]

Don't know where i am going wrong, currently in my console i get an error as :

```
 /sum_of_ideas/undefined/everything // so here id coming from the /ideas should have been rendered.
```

To make it clear i have used an example of {{idea.id}} and this displays just the number each time it loops.

Please help me in this, i want to use the response coming from the /ideas ie id in another response here it is /sum-of-ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `this.getSumOfIdeas(this.ideas.id)` you are trying to access `id` of `ideas` which does not exist. Either use something like `this.getSumOfIdeas(this.ideas[0].id)` to access `id` of the first object or use a loop to iterate over the ideas and call `this.getSumOfIdeas(this.ideas.id)`.

```
this.ideas.forEach(idea => this.getSumOfIdeas(idea.id))
```

Comment: This works, but as i load the page the value changes quickly i mean loops and every section gets the same value of getSumOfIdea method. So Can you please tell me where exactly to place it, such that every section gets its own value when iterated.

Comment: Where you have placed it currently, Is your question has the updated code you are using?

Comment: I have updated my code please check, i am displaying cards every cards has to display different information, every card is actually displaying different ideas.name and idea.id but same sum in all cards. I tried the answer you said me and it changes the value initially and then it stickes to one in all card

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of response from `/sum_of_ideas` api?

Comment: Suppose if i use /sum_of_ideas/3/everything an object is returned: { total: 200, max: 100, min: 49, ideas_in_month: 50, ideas_in_year: 60}, here u can see i have hard coded 3, but i want to use the id coming from the /ideas API in order to display information of a particular card.

Comment: Move your this.getSumOfIdeas call to the created hook below `this.ideas = response.data`

Comment: Yes i did the same thing as soon as you gave the answer, that's what when i open the page the values is displayed but it changes and then stops with one value, same case in all cards.

Comment: Try moving the method declaration form `methods` to `computed`.

Answer (score 1):

promise and async await both are used, use any one only.
execute `getSumOfIdeas` after assigning `this.ideas` which is in `created` hook

```js
    <template>
      <div class="Contents">
          <div class="vx-col" v-for="idea in ideas" v-bind:key="idea.id">
            ...
            <div>
              {{idea.name}} of {{idea.id}}
            </div>
            <div v-if="sum">
              {{sum.total}}
            </div>
            ...
         </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    ...
    
    created () { // remove async and await
    
       this.$http.get('/ideas')
        .then((response) => {
            this.ideas = response.data;
            this.getSumOfIdeas(this.ideas.id);  // Do this here after assigning ideas
         })
        .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
    },
    methods: {
    
      getSumOfIdeas(id){
        this.$http.get('/sum_of_ideas/'+ id +'/everything')
          .then((response) => { this.sum = response.data })
          .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
      }
    },
    mounted (){
      // this.getSumOfIdeas(this.ideas.id)   // move to created 
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried this way also, but same i get /some-of-ideas/undefined/everything rather i am expecting the id instead of undefined.

Comment: @build___ update your answer with `console.log(response.data)` after `this.$http.get('/ideas')`

Comment: Response of /ideas is an array which consists of objects inside it, each object as an id, sum-of-ideas and so on. I am trying to display the name and some-of-ideas of each id respectively.

Comment: this is to check if `this.ideas` has property `id`

Comment: @build___ how could an Array have property `id` ? your entire logic about `getSumOfIdeas` is wrong!

Comment: I have updated my question please check and let me know.

Comment: can you please give me help me